# How to check function is payable or not?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, erc20

How to check in code (on Solidity side or/and Web3 side) before call contract function, this function is payable or not?

For example I found this today in token EURS

```
function transfer (address _to, uint256 _value)
public payable returns (bool success);
```

This is not standard make erc20 transfer function as payable!!! And this is not standard logic make bugs in my app, if user use EURS token.

This is standard

```
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool 
success);
```

So I need, or override this is no standard transfer on my app contract side, or in worst case do ban such tokens on frontend side.

Answer (score 1):

In one line: there is no way to check externally or from within solidity if a function is payable or not without knowing the **abi / interface**.

What is payable?

- Payable works like any other **`modifier`** in Solidity. It runs just before executing the function it is applied on.
- Payable is required to receive ether. If you send ether in a transaction to a non-payable function the transaction is reverted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in one line-:

Any function which is marked as payable can be considered to receive ethers.

`function testPayable() external payable {...}`

The above function is payable and hence can receive.

But make no mistake **payable** keyword is only used to receive Ethers and not ERC20 tokens.

So in your case as far as I can see the transfer function is marked as payable, which should not be the case if it is ERC20 token.

Something sounds fishy to me, isn't it to you?

Comment: Yes, I know that this is a bug!

My goal is, can I check before calling a function in code 

like this: if (!isPayable(transfer))